# Bevorzugte Reihenfolge bei Adjektiven

Tags: adjective, word-order

Gibt es im Deutschen eine bevorzugte Reihenfolge für Adjektive? Z.B. würde ich immer „der große böse Wolf“ sagen, und nie „der böse große Wolf“. Falls ja, was sind die Regeln?

In anderen Sprachen, z.B. [im Englischen](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/order-of-adjectives/) oder [im Französischen](https://languagecenter.cla.umn.edu/lc/FrenchSite1022/ADJPLAbefore.html), gibt es häufig solche Regeln.

Comment: Ich finde [hier](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/t/adjektive-abfolge/5949040/6) die Antwort von Vokietis gut

Comment: Im Englischen gibt es diese Reihenfolge: Meinung, Größe, Alter, Form, Farbe, Herkunft, Material, Zweck, Nomen http://www.ef.de/englisch-hilfen/englische-grammatik/mehrere-adjektive-anordnen/ https://englishlive.ef.com/de-de/blog/die-reihenfolge-englischer-adjektive-und-warum-sie-wichtig-ist/

Answer (score 10):

Es gibt zwei Sorten von Adjektivreihungen: gleichwertige und ungleichwertige.

Gleichwertige Adjektive sind solche, die unabhängig voneinander verwendet werden können. Keines bildet mit dem Substantiv eine Zusammensetzung und keines wird als »wichtiger« erachtet. Klassischerweise ist die Gesamtbeschreibung identisch mit der Summe ihrer Teile; man kann zwischen die beiden Adjektive ein *und* setzen, ohne die Bedeutung zu verändern. Zwei gleichwertige Adjektive sind nach den Rechtschreibregeln durch ein Komma zu trennen.

> Das große, weiße Haus
>
> Das weiße, große Haus
>
> Das große und weiße Haus

Folglich ist das Haus weiß und es ist groß, aber darüber hinaus ist nichts Näheres bekannt.

Bei gleichwertigen Adjektiven ist die Reihenfolge egal und kann nach Belieben gewählt werden.

---

Nichtgleichwertige Adjektive verhalten sich anders; man könnte zusammenfassend sagen, dass das Ganze *mehr* ist als die Summe seiner Teile. Typischerweise gehört ein Adjektiv stärker zum Substantiv dazu als das andere. Ungleichwertige Adjektive werden nicht durch ein Komma getrennt.

> Die alte deutsche Schreibschrift
>
> <del>Die deutsche alte Schreibschrift</del>
>
> <del>Die alte und deutsche Schreibschrift</del>

Die Schreibschrift ist deutsch, also nach den in Deutschland gelehrten Grundsätzen. *Deutsch* und die *Schreibschrift* gehören eng zusammen. Das Wörtchen *alt* charakterisiert nun, *welche* deutsche Schreibschrift gemeint ist; man kann davon ausgehen, dass Sütterlin oder Kurrent gemeint ist. Zusammengefasst erscheint die Kombination spezifischer als die Summe ihrer Teile.

Ungleichwertige Adjektive sind in aufsteigender Wichtigkeit zu sortieren; das heißt, dass das Adjektiv, das dem Substantiv am nächsten steht, zu ihm die engste Bindung hat.

---

Und der »große böse Wolf«? Allein das fehlende Komma gibt uns schon den Hinweis, dass wir es mit nichtgleichwertigen Adjektiven zu tun haben. Der »böse Wolf« sagt an sich schon viel mehr aus, als es ein »großer Wolf« täte, man verbindet automatisch viel mehr mit ihm. *Groß* ist eine nebensächlichere Eigenschaft, auch ein »kleiner böser Wolf« wäre für Rotkäppchen eine signifikante Bedrohung.

Schriebe man »ein böser, großer Wolf«, wäre der Effekt zunichtegemacht und es bliebe nur noch ein aggressiverer, großgewachsener Verwandter des gemeinen Hundes.

Answer (score 0):

Meines Wissens gibt es folgende "Regel": Falls Adjektive gleichwertig sind, ist deren Reihenfolge egal (z. B. *der neue, kleine, grüne Becher*). Adjektive sind gleichwertig, sobald sie dieselbe Endung haben.

Des Weiteren gibt es Gradpartikel, die wie unflektierte Adjektive aussehen. Diese müssen zwingend vor dem zugehörigen Adjektiv stehen, da sie den Grad jener Adjektive beschreiben. Bei Gradpartikel handelt es sich um Adverbien, welche Adjektiven eine andere Wertung geben (z. B. *der winzig kleine Hund*).

Natürlich gibt es auch hier einige Ausnahmen, jedoch muss man sich dabei an sein "Gefühl" halten und die Adjektive so einreihen, damit es sie sich möglichst gut anhört/passt, daher kann man auch von reiner Willkür sprechen.

Comment: Jetzt wo die gröbsten Sachen weg haben, überlegen wir doch mal, warum der "böse Wolf" (!) immer als der "große böse Wolf" und niemals als "böser großer Wolf" bezeichnet wird. Liegt vielleicht daran, dass er der "böse Wolf" (!) ist. Wäre er der "liebe Wolf" wäre er der "kleine liebe Wolf", niemals der "liebe kleine Wolf". Anders sieht es aus bei dem "großen Wolf", der immer der "böse große Wolf" wäre und der "kleine Wolf" wäre immer der "liebe kleine Wolf". Und jetzt kommen wir zur Gleichwertigkeit. "Groß" und "Böse" sind nicht der Endung wegen gleichwertig. To be continued...

Comment: .... Du kannst die gleiche Endung haben und doch ungleichwertige Adjektive. Ich wünsche dir ein "schönes neues Jahr". Das Jahr, auf das ich mich beziehe ist das "neue Jahr", nicht irgendein Jahr. Und wenn ich  "schönes neues" sage, beziehe ich mich auf das "neue Jahr", das schön sein soll. — Ich hoffe, ich konnte den Punkt klar machen. Der letzte Satz im ersten Satz ist folglich übrigens daher nicht richtig.

Comment: Falls du eine Faustregel hast, würde ich sie gerne mal lesen. Jedoch sind "Grosse" und "Böse" in den Endungen gleich. Dein Beispiel mit dem "lieben kleinen Wolf" zeigt jedoch das es im deutschen Wohl kaum Adjektiv "Gruppierungen" gibt, wie z.B. im Englischen, da sonst "klein und gross" in der selben sein müssten.

Comment: Auch im Englischen kannst du die Regel brechen, wenn wir von **dem** "evil wolf" reden. Jegliches Adjektiv, was wir dem "evil wolf" vorsetzen, beschreibt den "evil wolf" und **nicht** den "wolf". Beim deutschen "bösen Wolf" beschreiben wir immer den "bösen Wolf", niemals den "Wolf". Die Adjektive "groß" und "böse" haben (flektiert) die gleiche Endung, das ist richtig. Aber sie sind **nicht** gleichwertig. Sie beschreiben **nicht** das gleiche Objekt. "Böse" beschreibt den "Wolf" und "groß" beschreibt den "bösen Wolf".

Comment: Nach dem was du vorher eingebracht hast, komme ich daher nur auf den Schluss, dass die einzige Regeln bei den Adjektiven darin besteht, dass Adverbien /inkl. Gradpartikel) vor dem Adjektiv stehen und alle anderen Adjektive frei sind, wir jedoch dabei auf die Reihenfolge achten, so wie sie für uns "normal" klingen.

Comment: Ja aber was wenn wir vom grossen Wolf reden? Auch dann würdest du wenn der Wolf böse wird, nicht plötzlich vom bösen grossen Wolf reden. Nicht?

Comment: Doch, genau das sage ich! Ich bin übrigens noch kein bißchen auf die Beliebigkeit der gleichwertigen Adjektive eingegangen. Darüber habe ich mir nicht mal Gedanken gemacht. (Ich weiß dazu nämlich auch keine Antwort.) Ich weiß nur, warum der "große böse Wolf" so ist, wie er ist. Du darfst da übrigens auch kein "und" oder Komma dazwischen setzen. Wir erzählen uns nämlich die Geschichte von "Rotkäppchen und dem bösen Wolf" und dieser Wolf ist immer der unzertrennliche "böse Wolf". Anders ist die Geschichte von den lustigen und frechen "drei kleinen Schweinchen".

Comment: Die Schweinchen sind nämlich die "kleinen Schweinchen", derer wir drei haben. Die "drei" steht vor "kleinen Schweinchen", weil sie die "kleinen Schweinchen modifizieren. Alle anderen Adjektive stehen vor "drei kleinen Schweinchen", weil sie die "drei kleinen Schweinchen" beschreiben. Die "drei kleinen frechen Schweinchen" sind übrigens andere Schweinchen als die "frechen drei kleinen Schweinchen". Die Geschichte der "drei kleinen frechen Schweinchen" darfst du noch erfinden, die gibt es nämlich noch nicht.

Comment: Mit Gefühl zu argumentieren, finde ich gewagt.

Comment: Es ist Gewagt, jedoch besteht meiner Meinung keine Regel, was bedueten würde man die positionen der Adjektive nach Gefühl zu ordnen. Ich verstehe deine Argumentation Em1. Wenn wir von einem speziellen Gegenstand oder einer Person sprechen dann kommen Adjektive die in Verbindung mit dieser/diesem stehen, antürlich zuletzt.

Comment: Jedoch gieng es mir beim Wolf nicht um den bösen Wolf aus Rotkäppchen, sondern nur um einen Wolf. Denn auch bei jedem Wolf würden wir vom grossen bösen Wolf sprechen und nicht umgekehrt. Ich finde jedoch im Moment keine anderen Beispiele dazu, möglicherweise sind wir durch Rotkäppchen so gerichtet, dass das Böse immer zuletzt kommt.

Comment: Um mal weg vom Wolg zu kommen: Ich würde auch vom "großen gefährlichen Nilpferd" und nicht vom "gefährlichen großen Nilpferd reden"

Comment: @Iris Aber genau hier ist es prinzipiell wirklich egal. Und das ist der Teil der Frage, der interessant wird. Und auch wenn es letztlich vielleicht wirklich reine Willkür ist, so wäre es interessant, wie der 08/15-Deutsche diese für gewöhnlich anordnet. Oder anders: Was sagt uns das Gefühl in solchen Situationen?

Comment: Ich sage ja dass es sich hier wahrscheinlich um Willkür handelt und es keine Regel dafür gibt. Beeinflusst werden wir einfach seit Beginn des Lernens und daher ist für uns eine Gewissen anordnung normal. z.B. wird ein grosser böser Wolf immer dieser sein, da wir die Aneinanderreihung aus Rotkäppchen kennen. Dasselbe passiert dann auch beim Nilpferd, wir tauschen nciht einfahc die adjektiven bloss weil ein anderes Nomen verwendet wird, es bleibt gross und böse, nicht böse und gross.

Comment: Ich sehe es als durchaus strittig aber nicht als Geschmacksfrage. Die alte deutsche Schreibschrift ist eben eine solche in der Abgrenzung zur neuen deutschen Schreibschrift, nicht zur alten französischen Schreibschrift. Dagegen kommt in den meisten Märchen weder ein guter, noch ein kleiner Wolf vor. Zwar kann man *böser Wolf* als festen Topos betrachten, aber man muss nicht. Wenn man es aber tut, ist *großer böser Wolf* richtig, sonst *großer, böser Wolf* oder *böser, großer Wolf*.